# App.js file running document.getElementById('age') on all pages? How do I contain this

Tags: javascript, function, getelementbyid

I have an app.js file that contains all my JS for all site pages. Within the app.js file is a function for age. The function runs fine on the page with the class of '.age'. But what is the best approach to avoid this being run on all other pages?

```
var start = new Date('09/20/1991 06:00 AM');
  var timer;

  function age() {
    var now = new Date();
    var age = now.getTime() - start.getTime();
    var year = (age / 31556926000);
    document.getElementById('age').innerHTML = year.toFixed(9);
  }
  timer = setInterval(age, 1);
```

Thank you and sorry if this is a silly question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the element exists and only then register the function:

```
let ageElement = document.getElementById('age');

// Check the age element exists
if(ageElement){
  var start = new Date('09/20/1991 06:00 AM');
  var timer;

  function age() {
    var now = new Date();
    var age = now.getTime() - start.getTime();
    var year = (age / 31556926000);
    ageElement.innerHTML = year.toFixed(9);
  }
  timer = setInterval(age, 1);
}
```